# Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement> | undefined'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Given this very simple component :

```
const InputElement => React.forwardRef((props:any, ref) => {
    const handleRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement|undefined>()
    React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        setChecked(checked:boolean) {
            if (handleRef.current) {
                handleRef.current.checked = checked;
            }
        }
    }), []);
    return (
        <input ref={ handleRef } type="checkbox" />  {/* <-- error here */}
    )
})
```

I have this error :

```
Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement> | undefined'.
  Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLInputElement>'.
    Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
      Type 'HTMLInputElement | undefined' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement | null'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement | null'.ts(2322)
```

What does this mean? How to fix this error?

Comment: Try `React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)`

Comment: Well, that was dumb. Why make the error so complicated? O_o This should be an answer.

Answer (score 251, accepted):

To fix the error, you should pass `null` as an initial value to the `useRef` hook. You don't need to add `| undefined`:

```
React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)
```

The error message says that the `ref` prop expects a ref of `HTMLInputElement | null`, but if you pass nothing to the `useRef` hook, it evaluates to `HTMLInputElement | undefined` and that's why get the error message:

```
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement | null'
```

---

To better understand what is happening, here is how you could reproduce the same error with a simple function:

```
// This function expects a ref similar to how an element like <input> does
const someFunction = (ref: RefObject<HTMLElement | null>) => {};

// the type of `ref` below will be RefObject<HTMLElement | undefined>
const ref = useRef<HTMLElement>();

// throws `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement | null'`
someFunction(ref);
```

Just how you get the error in the `ref` prop, you will get the same error in the function call in the last line. If you pass `null` to the `useRef` hook, the type of the `ref` would then become `RefObject<HTMLElement | null>`, which is compatible with what the function expects, thus no error is thrown.

Comment: For some reason it just never occurred to me that types can be null, especially when coming from other languages where an explicit `?` means "nullable" rather than "optional"

Comment: But why do I get such a misleading error?

Comment: Thanks, I had same issue and it is fixed by having the null

Comment: `React.useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null)` used with an `HTMLVideoElement` makes the application explode (cannot read null reading useRef error).

Comment: Thank you @Idrizi.A. Using `null`, it fixed my `ts` error

Answer (score 3):

I have the same error as follows:

```
Type 'MutableRefObject<undefined>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<Element> | undefined'.
Type 'MutableRefObject<undefined>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<Element>'.
Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'.ts(2322)
```

[image]

Previous codes are as follows:
[image: useRef hook]

[image: useOnClickOutside hook]

Passing `null` as the initial value in the `useRef` hook and as the first parameter `ref` type in the `useOnClickOutside` hook, the error has been fixed from my side right now.

The updated codes are given below.

The component file:

```
const notificationsTrayRef = useRef(null);
useOnClickOutside(notificationsTrayRef, () => setShowDropdown(false));
```

The custom hook file:

```
export function useOnClickOutside(
ref: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | undefined | null>,
handler: any,
): void {...}
```

Hope this will help others.