# Ref is NULL when wiring a component that expects LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement> | undefined

Tags: reactjs, tsx

I need to access the DOM element of an external third-party component which, according to its docs, supports the standard `ref` property as

```
ref   LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement> | undefined
```

First of all, I can't just declare a `useRef` or `React.createRef()` and wire that as `ref=` because that gives the error

```
Type 'MutableRefObject<undefined>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement> | undefined'.
```

So, [per this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74297048/1005607), I have to declare my ref with a `null` initial value as

```
const startDateRef = useRef(null);
```

So now, everything is wired up and there are no code errors, but I see that my Ref for this component is NULL! Does anyone have any idea why that would be? Am I missing something?

```
const startDateRef = useRef(null);

// It's NULL here in this initialization effect!
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('startDateRef = ' + startDateRef + " startDateRef current = " + startDateRef.current);
}, []);

            <DatePicker
                id="startDate"
                name="startDate"
                minDate='1900-01-01'
                onChange={handleStartDateChange}
                onKeyDown={handleDateKeyDown}
                defaultValue=''
                ref={startDateRef}
            />
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't you need forwardref? But DatePicker allows for a lot of customisation, sure you'll need a ref?

Comment: It's not the "standard" DatePicker. It's a custom third-party DatePicker.